# Extract data from HTML tags [ Automatically get start and end tags ] by php

Tags: php, html

Want to make a script that will automatically get content from html tags (start and end) and store them into an array.

Example:

**Input:**

```
$str = <p>This is a sample <b>text</b> </p> this is out of tags.<p>This is <p>another text</p>for same aggregate <i>tags</i>.</p>
```

**output:**

```
$blocks[0] = <p>This is a sample <b>text</b> </p>
$blocks[1] = <p>This is <p>another text</p>for same aggregate <i>tags</i>.</p>

NB: the first block start with <p> so must be stop at </p>, the second block again start with <p> but it has another start and end paragraph[<p></p>] between this, and stop when find </p> . That means i want to put all of the data and inner tags between start and end tags.
```

Comment: FYI, A <p> tag inside another <p> tag is not valid html

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to provide an answer to this, although this solution does not give you exactly what your are looking for, since nested `<p>` tags are not valid HTML. Using PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), you can extract the paragraph tags like this.

```
<?php

$test = "<p>This is a sample <b>text</b> </p> this is out of tags.<p>This is <p>another text</p>for same aggregate <i>tags</i>.</p>";

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($test);
$p_tags = array();

foreach ($html->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p) {
    $p_tags[] = $html->saveHTML($p);
}

print_r($p_tags);

?>
```

After throwing some warnings at you because of the invalid tag nesting, the output should be the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <p>This is a sample <b>text</b> </p>
    [1] => <p>This is </p>

    [2] => <p>another text</p>
)
```

Comment: sorry, maybe i didn't explain it better, again, this is not depends on '<p>' tag. our script will need to take first tag then take all of the data before the ending tag, whatever it is paragraph or bold.

    $test = "<p>This is a sample <b>text</b> </p> this is out of tags.<b>This is <p>another text</p>for same aggregate <i>tags</i>.</b>";

output:
Array
(
    [0] => <p>This is a sample <b>text</b> </p>
    [1] => <b>This is <p>another text</p>for same aggregate <i>tags</i>.</b>"
)
In your script, you separate the blocks depends on <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Simple Html Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) library to do this. Here is the example.

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');    
$html = " <p>This is a sample <b>text</b> </p> this is out of tags.<p>This is <p>another text</p>for same aggregate <i>tags</i>.</p>";    
$html = str_get_html($html);    
$p = $html->find('p');
$contentArray = array();
foreach($p as $element)
    $contentArray[] = $element->innertext; //You can try $element->outertext to get the output with tag. ie. <p>content</p>

print_r($contentArray);
```

your output is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is a sample <b>text</b> 
    [1] => This is 
    [2] => another text
)
```